# Make player jump when tapping screen

Tags: c#, xna

How do I call the following method on tapping on screen of mobile

```cs
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
   spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.player[currentframe], Texture.position, Color.White);
   currentframe++;
   if (currentframe > 24) currentframe = 0;
}
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: how to call this method on tapping on screen??

Comment: MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                currentframe++;
                if (currentframe > 24) currentframe = 0;
            }

Comment: i have done this but its nt working

Comment: well does it really need to be `puvlic?` instead of `public`?

Comment: srry buddy for spell error...its public